# Spark java group by and filter on custom condition

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have a problem statement similar to the following and I want to write it in spark job in java.

The input is like following where There is name of a person and their score

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 17 |
| A | 19 |
| A | 22 |
| B | 17 |
| B | 15 |

I want the output where if a person has score more than 20 then all the records of that person should be in the output. Since only person **A** has scored record of that person is in the output.

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 17 |
| A | 19 |
| A | 22 |

So far I have tried this code, but I am looking for a simpler way to achieve it.

```
 sparkSession.read()
    .csv("scores.csv")
    .toDF("Name", "Score")
    .groupBy("Name")
    .agg(collect_list("Score").as("Score"))
    .filter((FilterFunction<Row>) row -> {
        WrappedArray<String> scores = (WrappedArray<String>) row.get(1);
        return scores.exists(v1 -> Long.parseLong(v1) > 20);
    })
    .withColumn("Score", explode(col("Score")))
    .show(false);
```

I am hoping to optimise this filter function. In my original problem, the structure of row is complex and I want to use simpler sql conditional expressions like `any element with score > 20`.

Is there a way this can be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a window partitioned by Name like this:

```java
df
    .withColumn("max_score", max("Score").over(Window.partitionBy("Name")))
    .where(col("max_score").geq(20))
    .show(false);
```

Comment: Upvote but you mean `max("Score")` right?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry :) Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `join` with `filter`; first, you get a distinct list of `name` who have at least one `score` over `20`, as:

```scala
val filteredData = dataset
  .filter(col("score").gt(20))
  .selectExpr("name as r_name").distinct()
```

Then, you can use `inner` join to keep only the data you want:

```scala
val finalDS = dataset
  .join(filteredData, dataset.col("name") === filteredData.col("r_name"), "inner")
  .select("name", "score")
```

Final result:

```
+----+-----+
|name|score|
+----+-----+
|A   |17   |
|A   |19   |
|A   |21   |
+----+-----+
```

Good luck!